# {"Operation is not valid because it results in a reentrant call to the SetCurrentCellAddressCore function."}

Tags: vb.net

I have an error with this message {"Operation is not valid because it results in a reentrant call to the SetCurrentCellAddressCore function."}

The Error is come when I click a button in **Form1Main** to show a **FormSearchCompany** with code above, then close the form, after that I switch to **FormMain2** and then call the same form (**FormSearchCompany**) by click a button

The Error is come when I click a button in **Form1Main** to show a **FormSearchCompany** with code above, then close the form, after that I switch to **FormMain2** and then call the same form (**FormSearchCompany**) by click a button

if you like to see the full code is here

https://github.com/gedeeinstein/Surat-Jalan-PT-Dintara

```
Sub Data_Perusahaan()
    Proses.CloseConn()

    Try
        Proses.OpenConn()
        SQL = "SELECT tawar01.kode_pelanggan AS 'KODE PERUSAHAAN', " _
            & "pelanggan.nama AS 'NAMA PERUSAHAAN', tawar01.att AS 'PENERIMA', tawar01.kode AS 'PENAWARAN', tawar01.alamat as 'ALAMAT', tawar01.tgl AS 'TGL' " _
            & "FROM tawar01 INNER JOIN pelanggan " _
            & "ON tawar01.kode_pelanggan = pelanggan.kode " _
            & "WHERE pelanggan.nama LIKE '%" & Rep(txtCariPerusahaan.Text) & "%' ORDER BY tawar01.tgl DESC"
        perusahaan = Proses.ExecuteQuery(SQL)
        Try
            Me.DGPerusahaan.DataSource = perusahaan
            'Me.DGPerusahaan.Columns(0).Visible = False
            Me.DGPerusahaan.Columns(0).Width = 100 '**The Error is Here**
            Me.DGPerusahaan.Columns(1).Width = 380
            Me.DGPerusahaan.Columns(2).Width = 180
            Me.DGPerusahaan.Columns(3).Width = 190
            Me.DGPerusahaan.Columns(4).Visible = False
            Me.DGPerusahaan.Columns(5).Visible = False ' Untuk Memasukan Alamat ke Form utama
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try


        '850

        DGPerusahaan.GridColor = Color.White
        DGPerusahaan.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.White
        DGPerusahaan.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Purple
        DGPerusahaan.RowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.DarkGreen
        Proses.CloseConn()


        DGPerusahaan.Columns(0).DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
        'DGPerusahaan.Columns(3).DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter

        Proses.OpenConn()

        Dim myadapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
        Dim sqlquery = "SELECT tawar01.kode_pelanggan AS 'KODE', " _
            & "pelanggan.nama AS 'NAMA PERUSAHAAN', tawar01.att AS 'PENERIMA', tawar01.kode AS 'PENAWARAN', tawar01.alamat as 'ALAMAT', tawar01.tgl AS 'TGL' " _
            & "FROM tawar01 INNER JOIN pelanggan " _
            & "ON tawar01.kode_pelanggan = pelanggan.kode " _
            & "WHERE pelanggan.nama LIKE '%" & Rep(txtCariPerusahaan.Text) & "%' ORDER BY tawar01.tgl DESC"

        Dim mycommand As New MySqlCommand
        mycommand.Connection = Proses.Cn
        mycommand.CommandText = sqlquery
        myadapter.SelectCommand = mycommand
        Dim totalbarang As Integer
        Dim mydata As MySqlDataReader
        mydata = mycommand.ExecuteReader()

        totalbarang = 0
        If (mydata.HasRows) Then
            While (mydata.Read)
                totalbarang = totalbarang + 1
            End While
        End If
        lbl_totalperusahaan.Text = Val(totalbarang)
        Proses.CloseConn()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error. Hubungi IT atau periksa ulang data yang di input" + ex.Message, "Hubungi IT", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: You should look at the stack trace for the exception.  Basically, that error message is saying that you are doing something when a cell becomes that current cell that causes another cell to become the current cell.  Doing so could cause a stack overflow by making an infinite number of changes to which is the current cell and so it is not allowed.

Comment: Your code doesn't show anywhere that you're trying to click a button and open a form. If the grid containing your error is on form "FormSearchCompany" then instead of opening the form like this FormSearchCompany.show() try this instead Dim SearchForm as new FormSearchCompany   and then do SearchForm.show()    this way you can open 100 search forms

Comment: @Chillzy thanks, it solved my problem , I use ShowDialog before, then now I'm using just show :)

thanks for your help an answer

Comment: it's been a year hehe

Comment: No problems. I'm way too lazy to put it as an answer so if you don't mind putting it up for me and I'll vote it up.